# GAE: Find children of an ndb entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, foreign-keys

In the GAE I'm trying to find a way to implement or construct something similar to a foreign key constraint in a SQL database. Basically, deleting an entity that is being refered by another entity via a foreign key constraint should not be allowed (in other words: deleting a parent should not be allowed if there are children that refer to that parent).

I tried the `KeyProperty` in the ndb datastore but that gives me no options to find all depenend entites from the entity I want to delete. Also the `ancestor` hierarchy doesn't seem to cut it. I can query the `ancestor` from the children, but there doesn't seem a way to query the children from the `ancestor`.

Is there any way to either get the children from an `ancestor` or another database design in the GAE ndb datastore to implement this foreign key constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to either get the children from an ancestor

Yes it's called a query, used in conjunction with a KeyProperty in the child holding the key of the parent, or having the parent as the ancestor of the child key.

You can find all children of an ancestor irrespective of kind using an kindless ancestor query - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries?hl=en#Python_Kindless_ancestor_queries

There is no such thing as a foreign key constraint in the datastore.

Not sure how it doesn't "cut it" apart from not performing the delete for you.

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear enough... I have no knowledge about the child, and I have a lot of different children refering to the same parent. I could, of course, query all of them to see if they have that particular parent but then managing would become really annoying. I want to find out which and what children have a parent, without knowing the children.

Comment: Yes, and thats what a kindless ancestor query will do, have you read the docs ?  If you can;t use an ancestors then you are just out of luck.  If you children are similar (share many of the same attributes) then using a polymodel will allow you to query for a the base model for the key property. After that are no other options other than multiple queries or defining specific entities that are queriable for all kinds. (ie A Relation entity)

Comment: Ah indeed. I must've misread it (stupid me). This seems to do exactly what I want. I'm sorry for the misunderstanding :). Thank you for the help!

Comment: Just a few  things to remember about using ancestors in the childs key. This implies an entity group for the parent and all children. You cannot move children to a new parent, You have to copy/recreate them if you want to change, In addition you will rate limit your writes within the entity group to about 1write per sec.

Comment: I was aware of those limits, but I'm not expecting such high load that this will be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim points out, if you use the ancestor solution you can easily query for all children. The same would be true if you use KeyProperty; you can easily query for all entities pointing at the current key:

```
MyChildModel.all().filter(MyChildModel.my_key_property==my_parent_entity.key)
```

Again, it's not clear how this fairly simple solution wouldn't "cut it".

However it is worth mentioning that it is a fundamental mistake to treat the datastore as if it were a relational database. It is *not*, and you should not try. You cannot enforce referential integrity; eventual consistency makes that impossible.

Comment: OP did mention they had multiple Kind's of children " I have a lot of different children "  which implies a query for each possible child KInd, unless all children are based on Polymodel - which IMHO is too often overlooked ;-)